# I need to create an array for "Forms" to be called randomly

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have 4 forms (beside the main form) that I would like to store in an array and called randomly. The forms contain web pages with YouTube video clips that autoplay. When I use them individually in the code they work as expected. I am having trouble getting them to play from an array.

Comment: Can you show the code that you currently are using to add them to an array and also how are you trying to show them. also please describe the actual problem or error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approaches:

1. If the four forms are identical except for the specific YouTube URL, consider consolidating them to a single form.  You can send the URL to the new form via the constructor.  An array of strings is much easier to create.
2. You could generate a random integer (between 1 and 4).  Use as `Select myRandomInteger` statement with a `Case` to initialize and show the form for that integer value (index).
3. Finally, if you post the non working code, perhaps someone will have a more specific solution for you.